# Installing ubuntu over a 3 partitioned elementary os

Tags: system-installation

I have installed elementary os in 3 partitions, a / ext4 partition a swap partition and a /home ext4 partition.
All the personal files are and the /home partition.
So now I'd like to install ubuntu also in 3 partitions but without deleting the "/home" partition , even more I'd like for ubuntu to use the "/home" partition from elementary so that I don't have to backup anything and after installing all will be there automatically, is this posible?
I have done a test on virtual box but ubuntu just recognized the /home partition as a different disk that can be mounted, and the /home directory was empty , any ideas anyone??
thanks

Comment: You have to use Something Else. Chose current partition that is / and format it to ext4. Also choose current /home but DO NOT format it. Best to have good backups in case you accidentally tick the format box. But you have to include it during install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: it worked, just have to ask to use each partition without formating the /home as you said